# Sum of list without lowest and highest list integers (python)

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

Trying to practice my list comprehension, but at this point my code is looking a little (too) long per line length comprehension:

```
def sum_array(arr):
    return 0 if arr == None else sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1] for x in range(len(arr or [])-2))
```

Objective is to calculate sum of integers minus the min and max. If array is empty, `None`, or if only 1 element exists, the function should return 0.

I am receivingthe following

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Please advise!

Comment: I don't see any list comprehension..

Comment: For a start, don't compare to `None` by equality; use identity.

Comment: One-liners are cool.
But really, if you don't understand your own code, you may consider using multiple lines of code.

Comment: I don't see why you're doing that `for x in range(len(arr or [])-2)`

Comment: Worrying about `arr` being `None` is just a distraction. Assume that `arr` is at least a valid list of things you can add, and go from there. You aren't checking that `arr` doesn't contain strings, after all.

Answer (score 2):

> Beautiful is better than ugly.

```
def sum_array(arr):
    if arr is None or len(arr) <= 1:
         return 0
    else:
         return sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1])
```

Comment: `if arr is None or len(arr) <= 1:` can be written as `if not arr` only

Comment: `if arr` would fail on just about any *falsy* value. Better be explicit.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: An array with a single item is not falsy. Although `sorted` handles that, I'll rather be explicit

Comment: `arr[1:-1]` returns `[]` and the sum comes as `0` but then again "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: @RafaelCardoso If we pass boolean `False` into a function with your check it will return 0.  That's probably unintended behaviour, and it's much safer for it to error out on unexpected types.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need the `for` in the `sum`. It appears that `x` isn't used anywhere. This could be simplified to:

```
def sum_array(arr):
    return 0 if not arr else sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1])
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful and effective, thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know where both the max and min is is to sort the list.

```
arr = sorted(arr)
```

arr[0] is the smallest, arr[-1] is the largest

So

```
if arr is None:
    return 0
else:
    return sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1])
```

Comment: If there is only one element you need also return `0`

Comment: I suggest you try running the above code with only one element.  You may be surprised

Comment: Alright, you win, however [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says "Explicit is better than implicit.". So readability is also matter.

Comment: @vishes_shell - to check for one element, would I change it to read "if arr is None and arr == 1"?

Comment: To check how many elements a collection has, use the `len` function: `len(arr) <= 1`  `len` is short for length

Comment: @Mr.Jibz i believe @ MosesKoledoye 's answer is what you seek, because it more readable.

Comment: @vishes_shell I agree, but the incorporation of "not arr" is much more concise; that's the only portion i would change to his answer.

Comment: If you mean that I should use `if not arr` to check for `None`, I chose not to do it that way for a reason.  That would cause other "False" values to `return 0`, which is potentially dangerous behaviour.  Much safer to spend the extra keystrokes for `if arr is None`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version which meets your requirements:

```
def sum_array(arr):
    return (None if len(arr) <= 1 else 0) if not arr else sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1])

cases = [[j + 1 for j in range(i)] for i in range(5)]

for c in cases:
    print(c, sum_array(c))

# Requirements: Objective is to calculate sum of integers minus the min and
# max. If array is empty, None, or if only 1 element exists, the function
# should return 0.
# [] None
# [1] 0
# [1, 2] 0
# [1, 2, 3] 2
# [1, 2, 3, 4] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `TypeError` because you try to `sum` lists. Let me change your code a little bit:

```
 In[1]: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        [sorted(arr)[1:-1] for x in range(len(arr))]

Out[1]: [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

I change your generator expression on list comprehension to show the idea. Really you generate a list on each implicit `next` call. A further consequence of this error is:

```
 In[2]: sum([[1],[2],[3]])       # will raise TypeError
Out[2]: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

 In[3]: sum([[1],[2],[3]], [])   # if you specify start, it will work
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3]
```

The signature of `sum` function is `sum(iterable[, start])`. Sums *start* and the *items of an iterable* from left to right and returns the total. `start` defaults to 0. The iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string. In fist case you really try to sum `[1] + [2] + [3] + 0`, and because `+` between `list` and `int` is not defined, that's why you get TypeError. In the second case `[1] + [2] + [3] + []` this operation concatenates list and is perfectly valid.

And if you want review of your code and some feedback look at Stackexchange's [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

You can try this, if you like *one-liners*. Here is also an assumption that a valid array is always instance of `<class list>`:

```
 In[4]: sum_array = lambda arr: sum(sorted(arr)[1:-1]) if isinstance(arr, list) else 0
        sum_array([4, 3, 8, 1, 7, 12, 5, 9])
Out[4]: 36
```

**But it's not good practice!**